# finding out vertical pinch out in UIPinchgestureRecogniser?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios4

I want to increase width of UIView,when pinching out horizontally and also height only when pinching out vertically? is it possible in UIPinchGestureRecogniser?

Answer (score 0):

Not directly possible but if you were to maintain state yes. You can get the touch points using `locationOfTouch:inView`. Track them as he pinches and see which direction they are in. Update accordingly.